# The str must be of the form "# cents" where # is the total value of the coins

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get "150 cents" to be displayed in shell after I type in 
`print(dollar_amount(30, 0, 0, 0, 0))` in the idle window. But instead, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm using Python 3.

Here is the question below:

```
def dollar_amount(nickels, dimes, quarters, loonies, toonies):
    '''(int, int, int, int, int) -> str
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string formatting:

```
dollar_amount= (nickels * 5) + (dimes * 10) + (quarters * 25) + (loonies * 100) + (toonies * 200)
return "{} cents".format(dollar_amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

`"cents"` is already a string; change the rest.

```
str(...) + " cents"
```